# ParseError: 102 Invalid parameter for query: pipeline

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

After upgrading from Parse Server 2.8.4 to 3.1.3 an aggregate query in cloud code does not work anymore.

The query:

```
const query = new Parse.Query("MyClass");
const pipeline = {
    "sort":{"_created_at":-1}
};

const results = await query.aggregate(pipeline);
```

fails with error:

> ParseError: 102 Invalid parameter for query: pipeline

I also tried the pipeline object as array which also fails:

```
const pipeline = [
    {"sort":{"_created_at":-1}}
];
```

It seems to fail in [ClassesRouter.js](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/blob/d83a0b680854f52ce30205d3558c0133d7f8cf19/src/Routers/ClassesRouter.js#L161) which does not recognize the `pipeline` key.

Why is that?

---

Update: Opened an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues/5352) because it looks like a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating both Server and SDK to latest versions.

This issue may have happened because you used a newer SDK on an older version of parse or vice verse

Comment: I am not using the JS SDK as client, the SDK is only used through cloud code. I think Parse Server sets the required version for the JS SDK by itself according to the package dependencies? Using parse-server-example, these are the package dependencies: `"dependencies": {
    "express": "~4.16.x",
    "kerberos": "~1.1.x",
    "parse": "~2.1.x",
    "parse-server": "3.0.0"
  }`. When I only bump parse server to 3.1.3, the query fails.

Comment: Try to delete "parse": "~2.1.x",  from your dependencies as Parse-Server 3.1.3 will install it for you. See if that works. also ensure that when it does install that 2.1.0 inside your node_module/parse. parse-server 3.0.0 probably installs an older version of parse

Comment: Deleted `parse` dependency from parse-server-example. Deployed on heroku with `node_module_cache=false`, `npm list` shows `parse@2.1.0` installed under `parse-server@3.1.3`. Still getting the error.

Comment: Can you add a console log to see if it is coming from the class router? It should not go to the class router. I'll try it in cloud code now

Comment: I tried it in cloud code and it works for me. Does it work locally?

Comment: You were right, it was a Parse Server vs. Parse JS SDJ mismatch. I had two parse servers running on the same DB for testing during the update. Turns out that some URLs in the v3.x server still pointed to the other v2.8.4 server. ‍♂️ After correcting the URLs all works fine. Thanks!